# Select Item of dynamic list in HTML

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I'm doing a management application users have a part where I have a form with a `<select></select>`
Which is filled from a

```
@{ Html.RenderAction ("ListaTipoDeUsuarios", new {selected = 0}); }
```

This (Index.cshtml):

```
...
<div class="lg-xs-12">
   <label>Tipo Usuario</label>
   <select name="tipoUsuario" class="form-control" >
      @{Html.RenderAction("ListaTipoDeUsuarios", new { selected = 0 });}                                
   </select>
</div>
....
```

I have my function in the controller which performs the query to bring the list of types of users (HomeController.cs)

```
[ChildActionOnly]        
public PartialViewResult ListaTipoDeUsuarios()
{
  string dtTipoUser = client.GetTiposUsuario("{}");
  DataTable dt = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(dtTipoUser, typeof(DataTable));
  List<TipoUsuarioBO> listaTiposUsuarios = new List<TipoUsuarioBO>();
  foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
  {
    TipoUsuarioBO tipoUsuario = new TipoUsuarioBO();
    tipoUsuario = TiposUsuarioBR.MapeoTipoUsuario(row, tipoUsuario);
    listaTiposUsuarios.Add(tipoUsuario);
  }      
  return PartialView(listaTiposUsuarios);
}
```

And my view with the list (ListaTipoDeUsuarios.cshtml)

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <option value="@item.Id">@item.Id - @item.Descripcion</option>
}
```

My question is, how to make when loading the list brings one of the selected item.Currently when charging the view brings selected by default the first item in the list.

NOTE: Try changing the "0" of the "new selected = {0}" but does nothing.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to select an option when all options are getting  rendered? if yes, then refer below

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: Generate you view correctly using the strongly typed `@Html.DropDownListFor()` method to bind to your model property

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change the Model of the PartialView which is rendering the options. You have 2 options.

1. Change the existing TipoUsuarioBO object to add another property named SelectedID,

OR

2. Create a new Model with the following declaration.

   ```
   public class OptionsModel <-- Rename to naming conventions
   { 
       public List<TipoUsuarioBO> TipoUsuarioBO { get; set; }
       public int SelectedID {get; set; }
   }
   ```

And, while rendering option elements, use the following

```
@foreach (var item in Model.TipoUsuarioBO)
{
    <option value="@item.Id" @Html.Raw(@item.Id == Model.SelectedID ? "selected" : "") >@item.Id - @item.Descripcion</option>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't try using `List<SelectListItem>` as the model of ListaTipoDeUsuarios.cshtml view.

```
[ChildActionOnly]        
public PartialViewResult ListaTipoDeUsuarios()
{
  string dtTipoUser = client.GetTiposUsuario("{}");
  DataTable dt = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(dtTipoUser, typeof(DataTable));
  List<SelectListItem> listaTiposUsuarios = new List<SelectListItem>();
  foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
  {
    TipoUsuarioBO tipoUsuario = new TipoUsuarioBO();
    tipoUsuario = TiposUsuarioBR.MapeoTipoUsuario(row, tipoUsuario);
    listaTiposUsuarios.Add(new SelectListItem()
      {
        Text = tipoUsuario.Id+"-"+tipoUsuario.Descripcion,
        Value = tipoUsuario.Id.ToString(),
        Selected = true //if you want this item selected otherwise false
      });
  }      
  return PartialView(listaTiposUsuarios);
}
```

and your view

```
@Html.DropDownList("The name of the field", Model, new { @class = "any-class"})
```